# File type is undefined on android device native browser

Tags: android, file-upload, file-type, image-preloader

I need to preview the images before uploading, it is working fine almost on all android mobile native browsers, except version 4.2 or below. For eg Sony Experia L it is not working

I tried it, but file.type turned out to be undefined.

```
var files = event.target.files;
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
      var file = files[i];
      alert(file.type);
}
```